# Create CRUD for a self-referencing with Entity Framework 6.1 and MVC5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to Entity Framework, but I am working with EF 6.1 and MVC5 and trying to build a `Course` entity with a relation to itself (a `Course` has a pre-req course(s) one to one or one to many). How can I achieve that using EF and CRUD functionality?

My model is as follows: the physical model has a `Course` table that matches the `Course` and a `prereq` table that has 3 columns: `prereqId`, `courseNo`, `preReqCourseNo`.

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseNumber { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public decimal Credits { get; set; }
    public bool? PreReq { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DeptCourse> DeptCourse  { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> PreReq { get; set; }
}
```

and the goal is to be able to define these properties in the create page so the user can select a course number or multiples from a drop downlist and update the two tables with the relationship between them. A course can have one or more prerequisite course. Thank you.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this but isn't it a many-many (eg multiple courses can be a requirement for multiple different courses?) In any case you may want to add a "IsPreReqFor" reciprocal property so you can navigate in either direction. No doubt someone will give you the syntax for the foreign keys shortly

Comment: I do have a bool for a prereq checkbox where if a user selected it I provid a partial view with a dropdown list of courses to choose from.

Comment: I meant going the other way... Say course X requires A, B, C and course Y requires A, C, F. It might be nice when looking at course C to be able to say "This course is a requirement for both X and Y". There's no additional data required, just the ability to navigate the "requirement" constraint in either direction.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you asking for help with coding the CRUD part? If so, please show your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

As Basic suggested, I think this is really a many-to-many relationship. But if it really is a one-to-many, you could make your model like this:

```
 public class Course
    {
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public string CourseNumber { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public decimal Credits { get; set; }
        public bool? PreReq { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

        public int? PreRequisiteForCourseId {get; set;}
        public virtual Course PreRequisiteForCourse {get; set;}
        [InverseProperty("PreRequisiteForCourse")]
        public virtual ICollection<Course> PreReq { get; set; }
    }
```

In this scenario, each Course can only be a prerequisite for one course.

Comment: Sorry have been away on duty. Now the request is to have the ability to add a new course and in the process to be able to define one or more prerequisite course for example I am creating course 501 and I want to define that course 400 and may be course 405 is a prerequisite for that course so when a student register for a class that is attached to course 501 the system will check if he has the other course(s) taken before registering.